# Detect iOS device orientation lock

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

How can I programmatically check whether the device orientation is locked in iOS? I see nothing in UIDevice. I know that this is supposed to be transparent to the app. But I'd like to change the way I display content if the orientation is locked (as the Youtube app does; it locks to landscape rather than portrait). This must be possible.

Comment: The way YouTube does it isn't perfect either; if you left and went back to the app, the video will rotate to portrait if it's locked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way how to detect if orientation is locked or not. YouTube app doesn't lock to landscape, it just displays movie in landscape orientation, but when you rotate your iPhone, movie rotates as well (if there's no orientation lock).

IOW orientation lock is handled by system, transparent to your application.

If you want to achieve this functionality - just display your view in landscape mode even if the iPhone is in portrait mode and later enable rotation of your view. It will behave in the same way as YouTube app.

Update for comment:

```
.h

BOOL rotationEnabled;

.m

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  return rotationEnabled || ( toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  rotationEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: The only way I know to display a view in a particular orientation is: `- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation { toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;}`
But this then disables auto rotation.

Comment: Look at my updated answer. An example how to initially display in LandscapeRight and then allow rotation.

Comment: In iOS 6, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method is deprecated, but the new method `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` will give you the same behavior as this snippet does without any additional code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `UIAccelerometer` class to determine the phone's orientation in great detail. If  the acceleration vector enters a state where its largest absolute component is on the X axis, that is a landscape orientation. In theory this could be used to detect the orientation lock: if, within a few seconds of this happening, the controller does NOT receive a call to `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` property is not in landscape, you could then safely assume the user has the orientation locked.

This complicated, and has a delay because `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation` will be called well after the actual vector has actually entered a landscape region. The whole idea is a bit of a hack, and you should probably reconsider why you really need to present landscape views when the user has a preference not to show them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find out if the orientation is locked. I have looked for that some time ago and found nothing. What you can do is ignoring the orientation and just offer landscape in your view controller... then it will be shown in landscape no matter what.

I think this is what youtube is doing as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I feared. But youtube does detect the lock. If I hold the phone in portrait and open a video, it plays in portrait (and rotates as I rotate the phone). If I lock the orientation and do the same thing, it opens in landscape. This is not the default behavior. Youtube is detecting the lock and switching to landscape.

Comment: @wombat57 that **is** default behavior. The `-[UIViewController shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:]` is called when the lock is set or unset.

Comment: It does not matter if it is called when the lock is set; my app might not be running. The problem is distinguishing a locked portrait from an unlocked portrait. Chiefly Izzy has a good solution for rotation.